# How to add for loops to if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

In my code below I am not sure what order to put it in to work properly.

I first want it to print out for the user to select an option which it does, then if they select 1 it asks them their name and verifies it with the loop etc.

When I enter a name it starts to just loop the question enter your name and I don't know how to fix it.

Do I need to add more statements to my program, if I do then can I still use if statements for the user to select an option?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class username {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        {
            int UseLift;
            int AuditReport;
            int ExitLift;
            int a;

            UseLift = 1;
            AuditReport = 2;
            ExitLift = 3;
        }

        System.out.println("choose an option");
        System.out.println("Uselift(1)");
        System.out.println("see audit report(2)");
        System.out.println("Exit Lift(3)");

        Scanner d = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = d.nextInt();

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        // array containing usernames 
        String[] name = {"barry", "matty", "olly", "joey"}; // elements in array

        if (a == 1) {
            System.out.println(" Enter your name ");
        }

        String name1 = kb.nextLine();
        boolean b = true;
        int j = 0;// counter will start at 0
        outerloop:

        while (j < 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter your name");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            if (name[i].equals(name1)) {
                System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift, calling lift ");
            }
            break;// to stop loop checking names
        }
        System.out.println("Username Invalid");
        j++;

        if (a == 2) {
            System.out.println("");
        }

        if (a == 3) {
            System.out.println(" Please Exit Lift ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you plan to use java / doing programming further in your life ? if so, I recommend spending 2h reading java syntax overview, just go thru official tutorial from oracle.

Comment: no i dont great help @kiruwka

Comment: well, if you don't I guess it doesnt make sense to explain you how to change your code, its faster to write you working snapshot. Is it going to help ?

Comment: That would help, be greatly appreciated if you can@kiruwka

Comment: @user3151959: kiruwka was a little brusque, but you should pay attention to the main point, which is that the most valuable skill a developer can have is the ability to do research and find solutions.  If you don't understand Java syntax the first thing to do is study it.  Without this skill, and the knowledge of when to apply it (i.e. reflectively knowing what you don't know), software development will be very difficult.

Comment: @JimGarrison I accept and understand what youre saying but i dont want to become a software developer, i just have to do programming in my fist year lol, if i had more time i would be trying to do it myself

Comment: @user3151959 I provided you with working sample below

Comment: If you don't intend to learn how to program, hire a 12-year-old neighborhood kid to do your programming for you.

Comment: @HotLicks Do you imply I did the job of 12 y.o. for him ? I did it purely out of altruism.

Comment: @kiruwka - Well, you did put a 12-year-old out of work. :) But I wasn't really speaking to you.  If the guy's in a situation where he will need to have software written, and is not willing to do it himself, he should not rely on the "altruism" of SO but should make other arrangements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    String[] verifiedNames = { "barry", "matty", "olly", "joey" };
    System.out.println("choose an option");
    System.out.println("Uselift(1)");
    System.out.println("see audit report(2)");
    System.out.println("Exit Lift(3)");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        scanner.nextLine(); // get '\n' symbol from previous input
        int nameAttemptsLeft = 3;
        while (nameAttemptsLeft-- > 0) {
            System.out.println(" Enter your name ");
            String name = scanner.nextLine();

            if (Arrays.asList(verifiedNames).contains(name)) {
                System.out.println("dear " + name + " you are verified " +
                        "you may use the lift, calling lift ");
                break; // break out of loop
            }
        }
        if (nameAttemptsLeft < 0) {
            System.out.println("Username Invalid");
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        System.out.println("option 2");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println(" Please Exit Lift ");
        break;
    }

    scanner.close();

}
```

Comment: @user3151959 welcome. I know it feels offensive that someone asking programming questin isn't remotely interested in learning how to code, but I guess it is all normal. I still encourage you to just go thru code and see whether you understand logic enough to modify it in future. BTW, there are no loops needed as you can see.

Comment: one problem sorry you removed the couter for the attempts at the username, the user is allowed to have 3 attempts @kiruwka

Comment: @user3151959 I updated the code with attempts counter

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop below:

```
while (j < 3) {
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
}
```

will loop forever since j is not incrementing (j++). I believe you've mis-matched your curly braces at some point.

Comment: it stopped the loop but now it will not print out whether if the entrry is valid or not any ideas? @alyawn